# Snap a Vertex Group to a Surface

Tags: shrinkwrap

I need to create a consistent model for a Physics Simulation Program.(Comsol)[image] Is there any Way to snap these selected Vertices straight onto the Surface? Creating a water-tight closed System? I tried Shrinkwrap and Automerge but both didnt give me good results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose I recommend you to use [Shrinkwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) modifier which contains a lot of options to snap one object vertex ti another:

[image: Shrinkwrap before]
[image: Shrinkwrap after]